# self join plus another join

Tags: mysql

I have a table of country teams

```
id  country  group
1   Poland   1
2   Greece   1
3   England  2
4   France   2
5   Germany  3
6   Spain    3
```

I also a table of scores for each country

```
fromId  score
1       100
3       50
2       90
4       60
```

What I would like to do is get back a table of scores for each country within a group, having supplied just a country name. For example if I supply "France" then I would want the following table back

```
country   score
England   50
France    60
```

I have managed to self join the country table with

```
SELECT
`t1`.`fldCountry`,
`t1`.`fldID`
FROM tblteam t1, tblteam t2
WHERE
t2.fldTeam = t1.fldTeam
AND
t2.fldCountry = 'France'
```

but am now stuck how to joing this back to get the data!

Please could anyone help a little?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    c.country,
    s.score
FROM
    countries c
    INNER JOIN scores s ON c.id = s.fromId
WHERE
    c.group = (SELECT group FROM countries WHERE country = 'France' LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: I have chosen this one as it seems the most readable to me. Thanks to all of the other replies too though!

Comment: @Dave but you asked for a self join plus another join in the question?  All of the answers work and I believe Travesty3 had the first answer based on time.  Dave, I'm glad you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: This is what I struggle most with. I only use mysql occasionally and don't necessarily know the best approach, and there always seems to be so many ways to skin a cat! I tend to go with the solution that jumps out as most readable I guess!

Comment: @Dave: Readability is important, but performance is as well. It might be a good idea to benchmark my query vs. Dan's to see which one is better. I would say that his has a very good chance of performing faster than mine, even though mine may be simpler to understand.

Comment: To be honest, in this case, the database is only a few hundred records so performance is maybe not so important. Out of interest, how do you benchmark the performance?

Comment: @Dave: I use [Toad for MySQL](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) to develop my queries and it tells you the duration of each query, but you could do something in PHP alone. It could be something as simple as: `$beforeTime = microtime(true); /* perform query */ $duration = microtime(true) - $beforeTime; echo "duration of query = {$duration} seconds";`

Comment: Thanks for the link I will take a look. I currently use Navicat but can't see any way of getting duration of queries, but I will download Toad!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

**Country Table:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Country
    (
      id INT,
      country VARCHAR(20),
      grp INT
    )
INSERT  INTO  Country
        (
          id,
          country,
          grp
        )
        SELECT  1,
                'Poland',
                1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2,
                'Greece',
                1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3,
                'England',
                2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  4,
                'France',
                2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  5,
                'Germany',
                3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  6,
                'Spain',
                3
```

**Score Table:**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Score ( fromid INT, score INT )
INSERT  INTO Score
        (
          fromid,
          score
        )
        SELECT  1,
                100
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3,
                50
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2,
                90
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  4,
                60
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT  b.country,
        IFNULL(s.score, 0) score
FROM    Country a
        INNER JOIN Country b
            ON a.grp = b.grp
        LEFT JOIN score s
            ON s.fromid = b.id
WHERE   a.country = 'France'
```

**Result:**

```
Country      Score
England      50
France       60
```

Comment: Downvoted you until I realized what was going on. Probably no need to post all your temporary table stuff. Just confuses the answer.

Comment: @Kibbee: It makes it a complete testable answer.  It would be nice if / when people ask a question that they provide temp tables so that we can be sure of the schema intended for the answer.  However, the question is flagged as MySQL and I answered with MS SQL syntax.

Comment: Changed to MySQL syntax for temp tables

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
Select C2.Country,SUM(S.Score)
FROM Country AS C1 
INNER JOIN Country AS C2
ON C1.Group=C2.Group
INNER JOIN Scores AS S
ON C2.id = S.FromID 
WHERE C1.Country=@Country
GROUP BY C2.Country
```

Where @Country is the country you want to look up, in your case, France.